# Installing Ububtu on an older smartphone

Tags: system-installation, smartphone, ubuntu-for-android

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my phone Walton Primo D1?

These are some of the important specs of my phone:

Chipset

- MediaTek MTK 6575M

CPU

- 1GHz cortex A9

GPU

- PowerVR SGX 531

Sensors

- Proximity sensor, Accelerometer sensor(3D), Orientation sensor, Compass

Internal Memory

- ROM: 512 MB
- RAM: 256 MB

Extra Storage

- MicroSD: up to 32 GB

If possible, then how can I install Ubuntu on my phone?

Comment: @user281916: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/757249/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**